# Which of following is the largest?

Tags: inequality

> If $n=1/7+1/8+\dots+1/13$, then which of the following is the largest?
>
> (A)$1/n$
>
> (B)$1/n^2$
>
> (C)$n$
>
> (D)$n^2$

I used the AM-HM inequality which gave me $n\geq 0.7$? How do I determine whether $n$ is less than or greater than 1?

Comment: How many fractions in the summation? Are they all at most $\frac 17$? Now can you say if $n < 1$ or not?

Answer (score 2):

Because we have a sum of seven fractions and $$\frac{1}{7}+...+\frac{1}{13}<7\cdot\frac{1}{7}=1.$$

Comment: I did not understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @MrAP $\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{13}<\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}=7\cdot\frac{1}{7}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is B.

$n = 1/7 + 1/8 + 1/9 + .... + 1/13$

Which means the sum is a fraction less than $1$. Hence, $n^2$ is even smaller. Eg: if $x=0.1$, then $x^2=0.01$.

According to this, the reciprocal $1/n$ is greater than $n.$ And since $n^2$ is smaller than $n$, the reciprocal of $n^2$ which is $1/n^2$ will be greater than $1/n.$

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The sum is not necessarily less than 1.

Comment: @MrAP It will be less than 1, be rest assured as long as there are only 7 digits all less 1/7.